# how would I do a mass update in Realm Android?

Tags: android, realm

I am currently doing the following but I don't think it's the efficient way of doing it:

```
Realm defaultInstance = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
RealmResults<Stamp> stamps = defaultInstance.where(Stamp.class).equalTo("exerciseGuid", exerciseGuid).findAll();
if (stamps.size() > 0) {
    defaultInstance.beginTransaction();
    for (int i = 0; i < stamps.size(); i++) {
        Stamp stamp = stamps.get(i);
        stamp.setSynced(false);
        stamp.setName(newName);
    }
    defaultInstance.commitTransaction();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really a Realm user, but it [looks like](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/762) batch updates aren't implemented yet in realm-java and your way of doing massive updates is for now the only supported way.